# Does this thunk monad bind operation use more parentheses than necessary?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Given this thunk monad,

```
module FunMonad = struct
  type 'a t = unit -> 'a
  let return x = fun () -> x
  let bind m f = fun () -> ((f (m ())) ())
  let (>>=) = bind
end
```

I don't get why we didn't do `let bind m f = f (m ())` ? My guess is that it comes down to the very definition of bind in the first place: `a t -> ('a -> 'b t) -> 'b t`, is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, let's get rid of at least *some* extraneous parentheses.

```
module FunMonad = struct
  type 'a t = unit -> 'a
  let return x = fun () -> x
  let bind m f = fun () -> f (m ()) ()
  let (>>=) = bind
end
```

Now this `bind` function has type `(unit -> 'a) -> ('a -> unit -> 'b) -> unit -> 'b`.

If we do what you've suggested, it has type `(unit -> 'a) -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b`.

This is because OCaml's type inferencing has nothing to tell it that `f` actually takes a `unit` argument. As far as it can infer, `f` takes a single argument and is *not* partially applied.

Now, we *could* "cheat" and explicitly type annotate `f`:

```
module FunMonad = struct
  type 'a t = unit -> 'a
  let return x = fun () -> x
  let bind m (f : 'a -> unit -> 'b) = f (m ())
  let (>>=) = bind
end
```

But that doesn't seem like much of a win over the first version.

One might also get rid of that `fun () -> ...`:

```
module FunMonad = struct
  type 'a t = unit -> 'a
  let return x = fun () -> x
  let bind m f () = f (m ()) ()
  let (>>=) = bind
end
```

Comment: I see now a point I forgot to ask about, I meant: why we didn't return `let bind m f = (f (m ()))` if `f` returns type `'a -> (unit -> 'b)` instead of `let bind m f = fun () -> ((f (m ())) ())`? Didn't we duplicate the work?

Comment: Not sure you're still asking about `let bind m f = fun () -> ((f (m ())) ())` when the answer you've accepted says you can reduce the parens to `let bind m f = fun () -> f (m ()) ()`

Comment: And if we use `let bind m f = f (m ())` then `m` can be inferred to have type `unit -> 'a` and `f` has type `'a -> 'b`, so `bind` has type `(unit -> 'a) -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b`

Answer (score 1):

In an eager language like OCaml

```
fun () -> expr ()
```

is not equivalent to

```ml
expr
```

Indeed, the second one might evaluate a computation immediately whereas the first one will not start computing anything before `()` is provided as an argument.

Case in point, with `expr` = `f <lit>`,

```
let f x = print_endline x; fun () -> ()
let _one = f "Hello"
let _two = fun () -> f "World" ()
```

only prints the `"Hello"` part.